# Adding tags to photos on lovdbyless

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I'm writing my student project now and use lovdbyless engine for the basic social network functionality.
I want to add tags support to photos. I'm new to rails so the question is:
Are there the correct steps of doing it?
1. Add migration which creates 'tags' table in the database with id and name attribute and 'tagsphotos' table which has tag_id and photo_id fields.
2. Create model for tags that have 'has_and_belongs_to_many' for Photos
3. Add 'has_and_belongs_to_many' for Tags in Photo model. 
4. Now start using this things from controllers.

Is this organization effective? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either if you need to write it from scratch or use an already developed gem you need to explore [Polymorphic Associations](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association)

You can study either [acts_as_taggable_on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) or [acts_as_taggable_on_steroids](https://github.com/mattetti/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids) code.

This is the [migration code](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/generators/acts_as_taggable_on_migration/templates/migration.rb) for acts_as_taggable_on as an example

```
class ActsAsTaggableOnMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :tags do |t|
      t.column :name, :string
    end

    create_table :taggings do |t|
      t.column :tag_id, :integer
      t.column :taggable_id, :integer
      t.column :tagger_id, :integer
      t.column :tagger_type, :string

      # You should make sure that the column created is
      # long enough to store the required class names.
      t.column :taggable_type, :string
      t.column :context, :string

      t.column :created_at, :datetime
    end

    add_index :taggings, :tag_id
    add_index :taggings, [:taggable_id, :taggable_type, :context]
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :taggings
    drop_table :tags
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you and good luck with your work. If it works in stackoverflow you need to tick my answer or at leas upvote it.

Comment: Surely! I'm new here too, so I can't up an answer, but I ticked it.